# Calling .net DLL by using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects, dll

I had developed a tool by using C# (ArcObjects) and I want to (import that customized DLL and) call a particular function from that class by using ArcPy.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @PolyGeo: Hi, This is not a duplicate question. The previous question is about accessing the inbuilt method available in Arcobjects(esriGeometry.olb). But this question is about importing the customized Dll to invoke a particular function from that.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with your awareness of the earlier Q&A, and why you think it is not a duplicate.